# Rotating an end point while having the direction

Tags: c++, math, vector, rotation, game-physics

I have a point and a direction and I would like to know what that point would be if it was rotated by 45 degrees. For example, if I have

Point A being (0, 0, 0) with a direction of (0, 0, 1) and a distance of 5, then my point B would be (0, 0, 5). However, if I wanted to get what point B would be while also incorporating an angle of 45 degrees, how would I do so?

I had thought of using the Rodrigues formula, however, given the formula of Rodrigues being rotation = (v, k, angle), or in this case, rotation = (point b, direction, 45) I would have a resulting vector of (0, 0, 5). This leads me to believe that I should be applying the angle to the direction some how

[image]

Comment: You'll need to use either rotation matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), or quaternions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

Comment: @wohlstad I am familiar with both, but how would creating either allow me to find point C?

Comment: You must define axis of rotation.

Comment: @MBo How so? Isn't the direction the axis of rotation?

Comment: Its your question so you should know ... we can only guess ... to implement rotation you need center of rotation, axis and signed angle ...

Comment: No. In 2D you have implicit axis of rotation, normal to the screen plane, in 3D you have to define axis explicitly.

Comment: @Spektre I see, I just want to tell author, that in 3D he needs an axis (k vector in Rodrigues' formula).

Comment: @MBo Ahhh you comment OP author not me :) ... btw in reality we need plane of rotation not just its normal (ideally described by basis vectors) as axis of rotation is just human abstraction not corresponding with real geometry ... its just in 3D there is still just single plane corresponding to the axis so we ignore this ....

Comment: The set of valid points  `C` corresponds to a circle ... No unicity.

Comment: You add a bounty but still did not clarify ... so what is the axis of rotation (your `direction` ?) and what is center of rotation hardcoded `(0,0,0)` or defined as input point `A` ? ... I would go for rotation plane basis vectors and using simple 2D rotation formula no need to solve any system of equations ...

Comment: @judeclarke does my post answer your question? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to work in 3D, so you need to define a plane in which you want to rotate (i.e. move) some point. For example, given a point (0,0,1) and you choose the x-z-plane as plane in which you want to rotate the point, and you want to rotate it by 90°, you end up with (1,0,0). But if you choose to rotate the point (0,0,1) by 90° in the y-z-plane instead, you end up with (0,-1,0).

Rather than defining a plane, you can also use the normal vector of the plane in which you want to rotate the point. This normal is the rotation axis (called `k` below) around which the point gets rotated according to the [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#Curve_orientation_and_normal_vectors). So, if you choose the x-z-plane, the rotation axis would be k=(0,1,0), i.e. the y-axis. If you choose the y-z-plane as plane, the rotation axis would be k=(1,0,0), i.e. the x-axis.

Note that in 2D you do not have the freedom of choosing the rotation axis: It is always pointing straight "out of your screen". Meaning, you only have x- and y-coordinates, but for the purpose of rotating you imagine a third axis (the z-axis) which is orthogonal to both the x- and y-axes, i.e. k=(0,0,1).

Now, to rotate some general 3D vector `v` by an angle `angle` around a rotation axis `k`, you can use [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula). In pure C++ (since you added it as tag) without any additional libraries, it could be implemented like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <cmath>

using Vec3 = std::array<double, 3>;

// v = vector to rotate
// k = rotation axis. Must be a **unit** vector! (Length must be 1!)
// angle = rotation angle in radiant
Vec3 Rotate(Vec3 const & v, Vec3 const & k, double angle) {
    double const cosAngle = std::cos(angle);
    double const sinAngle = std::sin(angle);

    Vec3 const cross{
        k[1]*v[2] - k[2]*v[1],
        k[2]*v[0] - k[0]*v[2],
        k[0]*v[1] - k[1]*v[0]};
    double const scalar = k[0]*v[0] + k[1]*v[1] + k[2]*v[2];
    double const scalarWithAngle = scalar * (1.0 - cosAngle);

    Vec3 result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        // Rodrigues' rotation formula
        result[i] = v[i] * cosAngle + cross[i]*sinAngle + k[i]*scalarWithAngle;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here I implement e.g. cross and scalar products manually. Using an appropriate library such as [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) can make things easier and faster.

Given your explanation, I assume you want to start at a point A=(0,0,0), move a distance=5 into some direction. The direction is (0,0,1) but rotated by 45°. What you did not specify was the rotation axis. Considering your image, I guess to want to rotate around the y-axis (0,1,0), i.e. in the x-z-plane. Thus, in C++:

```
int main() {
    Vec3 const A{0, 0, 0};
    double const distance = 5.0;
    Vec3 const rotationAxis{0, 1.0, 0.0}; // = y-axis, i.e. rotation in x-z-plane
    double const angle = M_PI / 4.0; // 45° in radiant

    Vec3 const direction{0, 0, 1.0};
    Vec3 const rotatedDirection = Rotate(direction, rotationAxis, angle);
    Vec3 const C{
        A[0] + rotatedDirection[0]*distance, 
        A[1] + rotatedDirection[1]*distance, 
        A[2] + rotatedDirection[2]*distance};

    // Prints C = {3.53553, 0, 3.53553}
    std::cout << "C = {" << C[0] << ", " << C[1] << ", " << C[2] << "}" << std::endl;
}
```

This code first rotates the direction (0,0,1) by 45° in the x-z-plane, and then moves a`distance=5` starting at `A` along the rotated direction to get to point `C`.

If you already know the point `B` that you want to rotate, it can be done similarly:

```
int main() {
    Vec3 const B{0, 0, 5.0};
    Vec3 const rotationAxis{0, 1.0, 0.0}; // = y-axis, i.e. rotation in x-z-plane
    double const angle = M_PI / 4.0; // 45° in radiant

    Vec3 const C = Rotate(B, rotationAxis, angle);
    // Prints C = {3.53553, 0, 3.53553}
    std::cout << "RotatePointDirectly C = {" << C[0] << ", " << C[1] << ", " << C[2] << "}" << std::endl;
}
```

Full example [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/h9YaWaMz1).